# Modeling electricity prices ($/kWh) for Simulation

Tags: stochastic-processes, historical-data, simulations

I want to run a Simulation in Matlab that involves the running costs of an electronic device which consists of the power consumption of this said device. The simulation should run for the next 1-5 years. Since the (daily/monthly/yearly) \$/kWh electricity prices are not constant over time, my thought was to model them using a stochastic process which captures the changes over time. I want to calibrate the parameters of said stochastic process using historical data of $/kWh electricity prices.

Upon my research I found a lot about the modeling of electricity spot prices (e.g. [Comparison of Electricity Spot Price Modelling and Risk Management Applications](https://www.mdpi.com/1996-1073/13/18/4698)), but from my understanding (and please correct me if I am wrong) electricity spot prices do not reflect/represent \$/kWh electricity prices that I need for the running costs calculations. The explanations about mean-reverting models in different paper of spot price modeling are sound, however I am yet to find something that models \$/kWh electricity prices. I even thought about using Geometric Brownian Motion to simulate it, but in my opinion this would not fit.

Can someone point me in the right direction to a stochastic process that is frequently used to model $/kWh electricity prices and that can be used in my simulation?

Comment: Hi. One way of conveying a solution to your problem, is to figure out the stylized facts of $/kWh electricity prices. Then you can find a model that accomodates for some of these stylized returns (eg. seasonality, stationarity and mean-reversion).

Comment: Am not sure if you're the same person as the previous asker of a question like this (it now says 404 not found). But i asked there - what exactly do you care about - given it's running costs, i'm guesing base/peak load averages. Will you be consuming power 24/7? or do you have some flexibility to consume it during cheaper (i.e. baseload) hours?

Comment: And another question actually, which may significantly simplify things - why do you want to model it stochastically? Do you have some level at which it stops being profitable to run your device such that you'll turn it off? As if your payout is linear as a function of electricity cost, then you can just use the expected future cost.

Comment: @will Yes, for simplicity reasons I will be consuming power 24/7. To give you a better idea about this: this is about running a bot on a computer. The bot will make revenues but yields to power consumption costs. I was thinking about running the simulation e.g. 100000 times, the final result (i.e. the average of all simulation runs) should then tell me if it was profitable or not. This simulation should then help make a decision whether running the bot would be profitable or not.

Comment: @will The reasoning to model it stochastically was that the $/kWh electricity price varies over time and is not constant. To reflect those changes I thought about using a stochastic process. Similar as to stock prices which are not constant over time and therefore are modelled e.g. to follow a GBM.

Comment: @arely does your bot need to run 24/7? Or can you switch it off when the electricity cost moves above the profit generated by the bot? If you will never turn it off, and the bot's revenue generation is independent of electricity prices, then you do not need to know the distribution of power prices, only the expected future value (in which case you do not need to simulate).

Comment: @will So of course the optimal solution would be to turn it off at certain times, but for simplicity reasons I thought about just simulating running the bot 24/7.
The revenues depend on some stock prices, so I definitely need simulation for that. I model the stock prices to follow a GBM and calibrate it using historical data. But I don't understand how I should represent the changes in power prices in the simulation now that you say I do not need to. In my opinion they can't be estimated in advance since they are subject to change in the future.

Comment: If your payoff is linear with respect to the values of your risk factors (ie stock prices, electricity price, etc.) then you don't need to simulate them. You can instead just look at a linear combination of the future expected values.

Comment: @will Doesn't that apply always? When would I then ever need a simulation? (Not challanging you, I just want to understand this)

Comment: If your payoff is non linear, then you need the distribution in order to calculated the expected payoff.

Comment: @will I needed to do some research and my payoff is indeed non-linear, it essentially represents a long call option. Sorry I got confused myself a bit. So I still need to model the $/kWh electricity price. Do you have any advices for that?

Comment: @Arely so there are quite a few papers on electricity modeling. But it is somewhat location specific. You also need to factor in how you'll be buying the electricity. The prices available, and the reactive Ness with which you'll be able to take advantage of them strongly depend on who you are - if you're EDF, then you're going to be able to take advantage of very short term market behaviour. If you're just buying electricity from your server host, then much less so. Additionally location matters - the volatility of electricity prices is quite strongly dependent on location.

Comment: @will Would you mind linking me one of the paper that you have in mind? I'm not sure what EDF means, but I'm just buying electricity from a regular electricity supplier. About the volatility, wouldn't that matter only for the calibration? EU prices (e.g. Germany) is what I'm looking to model.

Comment: You can just google "modelling electricity prices", and EDF is a large french energy company which trades energy.

Comment: @will But this again yields me to spot price modeling, which should be quite different to modeling the $/kWh rate, which is the problem stated in my initial question. The $/kWh rate shouldn't change that frequently as spot prices do in my opinion.

Comment: @arely electricity prices are always something that can be turned into kWh. When you buy electricity, how do you buy it? Do you buy a fixed rate for some period of time? Or do you buy a variable rate? This is what you actually care about.

Comment: @will I mean of course unit conversion can be done, that is out of question. However, I'd still argue that spot prices are something different, e.g. they can be negative. For this simulation I'd assume a variable daily rate.